# A doubt on $d$-dimensional random walk

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider a $d$-dimensional random walk with equal probabilities in each of the $d$-directions (so, $p(v_i,v_j)=\frac{1}{d(v_i)}=\frac{1}{2d}$ here. Now, suppose the walker takes $2n$ steps. Now I have read in a book that "for large $n$" on average $\frac{2n}{d}$ steps will be taken in each of the $d$-dimension. I couldn't understand what is large $n$ doing here ?

Comment: @JaycobColeman: But, it is equal probability i.e. $\frac{1}{2d}$. So, does not that tell that the expected progress in each of the $2d$ directions will be same ?

Comment: I would recommend going back through your old questions and closing those which have been answered. The community generally frowns upon questions being left open if they've already been given a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @JaycobColeman: No, it is equal probability in each direction. This is the standard way $d$-dimensional random walk is specified.

Comment: @JaycobColeman: I am asking why this is true for "large $n$" only ? If probability in each direction is same, then expected progress in each direction will be same. Also, it was said in the book that this is due to law of large numbers. I am confused here.

Comment: I've deleted the comments to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look specifically at [Borel's law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Borel.27s_law_of_large_numbers). It essentially tells us that given probability $p=\dfrac{1}{2d}$ for each of $2d$ directions, as the number of steps increases, the chances of one direction having significantly more steps than another becomes smaller and smaller. This isn't true for only a small number of steps, however, because there are still reasonable odds of us having streaks of steps in some directions while possibly having no steps at all in others. It wouldn't make sense in this case to say the number of steps in each direction was approximately equal.

Two relevant quotes from the Wikipedia article:

"There is no principle that a small number of observations will coincide with the expected value or that a streak of one value will immediately be 'balanced' by the others." That is to say, there is no principle that says we should expect to have $\approx\dfrac{n}{d}$ steps in a given direction when $n$ is small.

"This theorem[BLoLN] makes rigorous the intuitive notion of probability as the long-run relative frequency of an event's occurrence." So as $n\to\infty$, the proportion of steps taken in a particular direction will be $\dfrac{1}{2d}$.

Comment: The OP asks why it's only stated "for large $n$" that on average $2n/d$ steps will be taken in each of the $d$ directions. The key phrase here is *on average.* For small $n$, is it not still true that *on average,* over many walks, $2n/d$ steps will be taken in each direction? What exactly is it that's true only for large $n$ here that isn't true for small $n$?

Comment: I took OP's usage of "on average" to mean "approximately," since that is what makes sense in context. There would not be any difference between the result of taking an average over many walks with a small number of steps and a single walk with many steps. I think OP is talking about a single walk. What is false for small $n$ is that we could expect approximately $n/d$ steps to have been taken in a given direction, which in the answer I give two reasons for. I think you've misinterpreted the question. Also, $2n/d$ steps aren't taken in each direction; that is true for each dimension.

Comment: But all OP needs to understand the question is Borel's law of large numbers, and the specifics of talking in terms of direction or dimension aren't really important here.

Comment: Yes, I should have said "in each *dimension*", but I don't a mathematics book would (should?) have written "on average" to mean "approximately." I think the OPs statement that "on average, $2n/d$ steps will be taken in each of the $d$ dimensions is true without the qualifier "for large $n$." Isn't the expected value, for a random walk of $2n$ steps, of the number of steps in a given dimension, exactly equal to $2n/d$ for any value of $n$, large or small?

Comment: @SteveKass It definitely should not, but perhaps this is OP's phrasing. We still would need the qualifier "for large $n$" since how many steps we'd expect to have to take to see this pattern emerge depends on how large $d$ is. To put it another way, yes, the expected value is exactly $2n/d$, but the expected value is something reached only in the limit as $n\to\infty$. As quoted, "There is no principle that a small number of observations will coincide with the expected value."